# from html "array" to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've a html page that is made quite like this:

```
<table id="all">
<tr><td><input type="text" name="search[id]" id="search[id]"></input></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="search[name]" id="search[name]"></input></td></tr>
..........ecc ecc..........
</table>
```

i want with javascript or jquery achieve an array made like this:

```
{
id:"<value in search[id]>",
name:"<value in search[name]>",
....ecc ecc...
}
```

the keys of the array aren't static so i can't name them statically in the code.
i tried with $("#search") but i haven't been lucky :(
Thank you very much for the help!
and sorry for the noob question!

Comment: What you're asking for isn't actually an "array", which is linear and number-indexed. It's a JavaScript object, which is comparable to an associative array in PHP.

Comment: {name: value, ...} is an Object literal defining an Object not an Array. An JavaScript Array can be defined with its Array literal [value0, value1, value2, ...]

Comment: how is the html generated?  If you're writing it by hand you're going to want to rewrite the ids for each input to be more clear.  Also neither of these things are actually arrays.  The HTML is a table, the JS is an object.

Comment: Have you considered using `$("#myformid").serializeArray()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides `$(form).serializeArray()` [as documented on their API site](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) (always worth a quick look, that one).

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {};
$('#all [id^=search]').each(function() {
   obj[this.id.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]] = this.value;
});
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsbin.com/ekalir/3/)

Comment: I think you'd have to escape that `[` inside the selector.

Answer (score 0):

This is do-able in *native JavaScript*; assuming your HTML

```
function nameToObj(queryName, nodes, context) { // `nodes`, `context` optional
    var o = {}, i, j = queryName.length; // var what we'll need
    context || (context = document);
        // if `context` falsy, use `document`
    nodes || (nodes = context.getElementsByTagName('input'));
        // if `nodes` falsy, get all <input>s from `context`
    i = nodes.length; // initial `i`
    while (i--) { // loop over each node
        if (nodes[i].name.slice(0,j) === queryName) { // test
            o[nodes[i].name.slice(j+1,-1)] = nodes[i].value;
                // match, append to object
        }
    }
    return o; // return object
}
nameToObj('search'); // Object {name: "", id: ""}
```